# Adding lime juice to green curry paste and heating

Tags: nutrient-composition, curry, lime

I am trying this recipe which requires preparation of a green curry paste with lime juice as one of the ingredients. Once the paste is prepared, I add it to a pan with hot oil (after which I add coconut milk to the paste)

My doubt is - is it a good idea to add lime juice to a hot mixture because the heat probably destroys the vitamins in it? Or is it better to add lime juice later towards the completion of the preparation of the dish?

Comment: You're rather close to asking a nutritional question here, and those are off topic. Fortunately the two answers so far are culinary, but it seems easy to read this as asking about nutrition. Perhaps you'd like to edit to avoid asking about vitamins at all?

Answer (score 5):

Lime juice is one of the components of green curry.  The acid from the lime juice macerates some of the other ingredients and wakens up some other flavors. If you don't add it as part of the paste preparation, then you aren't cooking with Green Curry.

If you add the lime juice in the end, you will have a very different result, mostly that of a dish that tastes like it was sprinkled with lime juice before served.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it's not so much about the vitamins as the taste.  All the citrus juice I've ever tried to cook with has lost most of it's flavor and become bitter when heated for more than a few minutes.  Zest can be added earlier (and will give some good flavor) but I'd save any citrus juice for near the end of the recipe.

Answer (score 3):

When you add lime juice to any dish and heat it,  the flavours of the dish are lost... You surely are trying to get a citrus flavour of lemon which will be pretty much suppressed if you heat it.  In case you need lemon aroma,  crush lemon grass; tie in a cloth and put it in ur curry and boil.. After few minutes remove the cloth.  If you need the Tangy flavor.. Add lemon juice after your curry has settled and a bit cooled.. Not when hot.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score -1):

I add a sprinkle of lime at the end when you have it plated it doesn’t taste like lime added it wakes all the flavors